# Merging selector @extend issue

Tags: css, sass, bem

I have a problem about "@extend" directive in SCSS.

```
    .header {
         .introduction-group {
         text-align: center;
         color: $white;
         width: 70%;
      }
    .about {
      &__description-group {
        @extend .introduction-group;
```

This code block does not work. However,

```
    .header {
         &__introduction-group {
         text-align: center;
         color: $white;
         width: 70%;
      }
    .about {
      &__description-group {
        @extend .header__introduction-group;
```

Second one works. Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) nested classes won't be applied with @extend. Your second code block targets the specified class including the parent prefix. The first code block doesn't, it only targets the nested class.

I made a small [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/laura46/pen/poyLqQJ?editors=1100) to illustrate the problem in a simple way. Make sure you checkout the [Sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) for a more comprehensive explanation!

```
<h1 class="wrong">Test style gone wrong</h1>
<h1 class="right">Test style gone right</h1>
.test {
  .nested {
    color: red;
  }
  &-nested {
    color: red;
  }
}
.wrong {
  @extend .test;
  @extend .nested;
}
.right {
  @extend .test-nested;
}
```